# How could I download the old openstreetmap xml data? (after redaction lots of streets disappeared)

Tags: openstreetmap

It seems openstreetmap has changed their licensing scheme, as a result lots of data were deleted, as shown in the attached picture which is Grafton, NSW 2460, Australia, almost all streets are gone.

My question is: is there any way to download the old data somewhere by providing lat/lng's? (I understand that there could be some old archives for WORLD or some countries, but that doesn't work for me because at the moment my application is not capable to process those massive data files)

If there's no way to download the old data, is there any other good free map data (not images) available?

Also I've noticed that there're 4 options at the top right corner, the other three except standard seem to be showing all streets. They are (at least MapQuest) based on osm data, but not the one we get from the "export" section of openstreetmap.org, is that correct?

EDIT: OOPS, as a new user I cannot post images.. the below link may work (or may not):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieIxt.png

(It's just 2 snapshots of Grafton, NSW 2460, Australia, one of Standard, one of MapQuest Open)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data previously available under CCBYSA, are no longer to be used (re added) to the current ODBL OpenStreetMap Database. You are free to remap the area or to use a CCBYSA extract to show your users.

To answer your question: as of today there is no way of downloading the old data in an easy way.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly in Australia there was quite a few awkward people who preferred to see all their data removed, rather than agreeing to the (very minor!) license change. With this behind us the project is on a better legal footing, and (as I see it) we've dispensed with a lot of awkward troublemakers in the process. Things are looking up. We had a big push to fill in the new gaps in Australia, working quickly from aerial imagery.

But we do still need help. [Your Grafton example is looking a lot better](http://www.openstreetmap.org/?lat=-29.683&lon=152.9397&zoom=14&layers=M) now, but it shows that we still need local people to go there on-the-ground to gather details, particularly street names, to put on the map. By using the live map as it is, you help bring attention to such problems, and encourage people join in the mapping fun!